# which runs faster sql or plsql if both produces same result?

Tags: sql, plsql

> *which runs faster sql or plsql if both produces same result?*

This question was asked to me in interview.

Comment: I assume plsql involves some functions,but this is as vague as they come

Comment: ask the explain plan...
in general, i think that is that kind of question, which will test you how you perform with that kind of stupid questions. As other mentioned thats no question you can answer correct without having more details.

Comment: I guess it was meant to be an open-ended question for discussion, to what you know about the differences.

Comment: I agree with Tony in the previous comment. Maybe the interviewer wanted to know if you were aware of [context switching](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602)?

Comment: If I was asked that in an interview, I would say, "I don't know".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean ansi SQl. In general, the answer would be specific to the way the two queries were written. You can write a bad query in either language to produce the same result. However, most of the time, the database vendors code written specifically for that engine will outperform generic SQl for complex tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way the question was asked. As of myself, I understand it like _"which run faster: a declarative query using SQL, or an imperative procedure using PLSQL?"_